# Is it possible to override an integer array in Java?

Tags: java, overriding

I have an ArrayList `ArrayList<int[]>` which has one-dimensional array of integers as it's members.

When I am debugging and have my watch set on `tmp` from the code below, I want to be able to see `tmp`'s contents, which means I have to override the `toString` method of `int[]`?

At the moment, I am able to see my contents by printing them out using the `print` method below. However, I do not want to do that ideally, and would like to see the contents of `tmp` and it's members from the debugger.

PS : I do not want to have debug watch expressions like, say, `tmp.get(0)[0]` etc

```
public class TryPrinting {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[][] people = { {7,0}, {7,1}, {6,1}, {5,0}, {5,2}, {4,4} };

        TryPrinting obj = new TryPrinting();
        obj.test( people );
    }

    public void test( int[][] people)
    {
        int n = people.length;
        ArrayList<int[]> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            tmp.add(people[i][1], new int[]{people[i][0], people[i][1]});

            print( tmp );//This works
            System.out.println( tmp );//But I want this to work
            System.out.println( "" );
        }

    }

    /* print al */
    public void print( ArrayList<int[]> al )
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<al.size();i++)
        {
            print( al.get( i ) );
        }
        System.out.println( "" );
    }

    /* print 1d array */
    public void print(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print( a[i] + " " );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can if you box int to Integer, it becomes an object with a class type, I guess you'll get toString too...

Comment: The comments on your code implies you're trying to print to console, but your question implies you want your debugger to display it. Which is it? And which IDE are you using?

Comment: In response to your question title, the answer is No.

Answer (score 2):

Array classes are `final`: you cannot extend them and override their methods.

To easily print contents of an array, you can use methods in `java.util.Arrays`, like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
```

An alternative is to use `List`s in place of arrays, which implement a "proper" `toString` method.